# creating multiple threads in C issue

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

im beginner in C system programing, im trying to write  a code in C that use threads to realise the graph in the photo,[click here to see the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM9tK.jpg) so i have write this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_1(void *arg){
    printf("je suis le thread 1.\n");
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
void *thread_2(void *arg){
    printf("je suis le thread 2.\n");
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

void *thread_3(void *arg){
    printf("je suis le thread 3.\n");
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

void *thread_4(void *arg){
    printf("je suis le thread 4 et je suis lance apres la fin du thread 1.\n");
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

void *thread_5(void *arg){
    printf("je suis le thread 5  et je suis lance apres la fin du thread 1 et le thread 2.\n");
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

void *thread_6(void *arg){
    printf("je suis le thread 6  et je suis lance apres la fin du thread 3 et le thread 5.\n");
    (void) arg;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

int main(void){
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;
    pthread_t thread4;
    pthread_t thread5;
    pthread_t thread6;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread_2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, thread_3, NULL);
    if(pthread_join(thread1, NULL)){
        pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, thread_4, NULL);
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pthread_join(thread1, NULL) && pthread_join(thread2, NULL)){
        pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, thread_5, NULL);
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pthread_join(thread3, NULL) && pthread_join(thread5, NULL)){
        pthread_create(&thread6, NULL, thread_6, NULL);
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pthread_join(thread4, NULL) && pthread_join(thread6, NULL)){
        printf("je suis l'etape 7 et la fin.\n");
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else{
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when this code is excuted i get this message

```
je suis le thread 2.
je suis le thread 1.
je suis le thread 3.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

what i want it to be is that the threads are created in sort to be like the graph mean 1-2-3 then 4 after 1 ends and 5 after 1 and 2 ends, 6 will be created after 3 and 5 ends and the last instruction will be excuted
after 6 and 4 ends, can anyone show me what i did wrong

Comment: I'm not getting the logic. There's a strong possibility that `thread5` isn't initialized.

Comment: "If successful, the pthread_join() function shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error."

Comment: On windows, I get the following:je suis le thread 1.
je suis le thread 2.
je suis le thread 3.
je suis l'etape 7 et la fin.
pthread_join: No error

Comment: The second call to phread_join using the argument thread1 will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_join` returns 0 when OK. You have a logic problem in your code, running next threads only if failed, and returning with errors at the same time!

The problem you get is that with all that wrong logic you try to join on `thread5` which is not initialized.

Attempt to fix your code, just adding a couple of `else` statements & changed tested values against 0, now it makes sense:

```
int main(void){
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;
    pthread_t thread4;
    pthread_t thread5;
    pthread_t thread6;
    if (pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_1, NULL))
        {
           perror("pthread_create 1");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

   if (pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread_2, NULL))
        {
           perror("pthread_create 2");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    if (pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, thread_3, NULL))
      {
         perror("pthread_create 3");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

    if(pthread_join(thread1, NULL)==0){
        if (pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, thread_4, NULL))
        {
           perror("pthread_create 4");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pthread_join(thread2, NULL)==0){
        if (pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, thread_5, NULL))
        {
           perror("pthread_create 5");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pthread_join(thread3, NULL)==0 && pthread_join(thread5, NULL)==0){
        if (pthread_create(&thread6, NULL, thread_6, NULL))
        {
           perror("pthread_create 6");
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if(pthread_join(thread4, NULL)==0 && pthread_join(thread6, NULL)==0){
        printf("je suis l'etape 7 et la fin.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        perror("pthread_join");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, mostly, but you cannot join thread1 twice, as your code does.  But once the main thread joins thread1, it doesn't need to do so again anyway.

Comment: I saw it the first time, but got overwhelmed by the flawed logic. Thanks (I actually did not test that)

Comment: thank you, the code works perfectly now, but i still dont understand why you say that thread5 is not initialised??

Comment: in your original code, since return codes were reversed, you never created thread5, but you tried to join it, thus using the `thread5` variable uninitialized for `join`, which explains the crash (`thread3` was OK)

Comment: ahh, thank you again, i start getting the logic of this now